# Excel Match Less Than or Equal To

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I am trying to combine Index & Match to pull the value inside of Column B based on if a number is less than or equal to the value inside of Column A on the same row. So for example if I give the formula `0` than I would like it to return `0.75`, `15.25` should return `0.80`, etc.

The current formula that I came up with sort of does this but it isn't right. If I put in `0` I would get `#N/A` and if I put in `15.25` than I get `0.75` which isn't correct.

```
=INDEX(B1:B11,MATCH(A13,A1:A11))
```

[image: Example Chart]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem comes from the fact that the `MATCH` statement will return "#N/A" if it does not find the value. So the `INDEX`statement will not know what to do with this, so you have to manage this case. An `IF`statement should be good to deal with this.

> =IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11))

With the example above, if you have a value that is smaller than the first number of your array, it will return 0. Next you have to plug this into the `INDEX`statement.

Next you have to manage the fact that you want to round up and not down. This can also be managed easily with and `IF`statement. You can simply compare the number in the A column with the target cell to see if they are the same, if not you increment your row by 1. You'll just have to nest `IF`statements within each other with some help from the `INDEX`statement.

> =IF(INDEX(A1:A11,IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11)))=A13, IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11)), IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11))+1)

So this will basically make it that it now rounds up instead of down.

The last step is to make it so that you get the value of the 2nd column instead of the first one. You had this correct with the `INDEX` statement, we just need to put them all together.

> = INDEX(B1:B11,IF(INDEX(A1:A11,IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11)))=A13, IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11)), IF(A1>A13,0,MATCH(A13,A1:A11))+1) )

And this gives exactly the results you wanted in your question. Sorry for the long formula, but you wanted something more or less complicated.

Comment: After looking over your formula it appears there is an issue with it and if `A13` is set to something like `14` it returns `#VALUE!`. But I did some tweaking and made the following which works.

`=INDEX(B1:B11, IF(A1 > A13, 1, IF(INDEX(A1:A11, MATCH(A13,A1:A11)) = A13, MATCH(A13,A1:A11), MATCH(A13,A1:A11)+1)))`

Comment: That's weird because it works fine with my version of Excel and your exact dataset. Anyways, glad it helped you get your answer.